# get_pages() Returns Only One Item

Tags: functions, theme-development, shortcode

I'm trying to list the children of a specific parent page for use in a shortcode using get_pages(). Unfortunately, only one page is being displayed though there are many more that should be displayed.

```
// List Vocations
function get_vocations_list() {

    $args = array (
        'parent' => '753',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'desc'
    );
    $voc_pages = get_pages($args);

    foreach( $voc_pages as $voc_page ) {
        $voc_link = '<a href="'.get_page_link( $voc_page->ID ).'">'.$voc_page->post_title.'</a>';
        return $voc_link;
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'vocations_list', 'get_vocations_list' );
```

I've been unsuccessful in troubleshooting this and hope to get some insight from the community as why this is occurring and possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this section

```
foreach( $voc_pages as $voc_page ) {
    $voc_link = '<a href="'.get_page_link( $voc_page->ID ).'">'.$voc_page->post_title.'</a>';
    return $voc_link;
}
```

You return `$voc_link` after just the first iteration, stopping the function and returning its value. You should take `return $voc_link;` outside your foreach loop, and probably save your links as an array

Change the above section to

```
foreach( $voc_pages as $voc_page ) {
    $voc_link[] = '<a href="'.get_page_link( $voc_page->ID ).'">'.$voc_page->post_title.'</a>';
}
return $voc_link;
```

### EDIT

From your comment

> This only returns "Array" instead

You are most probably trying to echo the function. You cannot echo an array, this will just print the word `Array`

As the function returns an array, you have two choices

### OPTION 1

Put the output through a `foreach` loop

```
$links = get_vocations_list();
foreach ( $links as $link ) {

    echo $link;

}
```

### OPTION 2

Convert the array to a string inside the function and then return the string

```
foreach( $voc_pages as $voc_page ) {
    $voc_link[] = '<a href="'.get_page_link( $voc_page->ID ).'">'.$voc_page->post_title.'</a>';
}

$voc_link = implode( '</br>', $voc_link );
return $voc_link;
```

And then use the function as

```
echo get_vocations_list();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, it is not a working solution. This only returns "Array" instead.

Comment: Will update my answer

Comment: @CChoma You either need to build an array and `return` that, as suggested by @PieterGoosen, or `echo $voc_link`.  [`Return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) "immediately ends the current function's execution".

Comment: @m0r7if3r - I did try that and it did not work. echo can't be used in functions used in shortcodes. return must be used. Note that the function works fine when inserted in a template file and return is replaced with echo. But when adding it to functions.php and only changing echo with return, it breaks.

Comment: @CChoma See my update

Comment: @Pieter Goosen - I see now. I like option 2. Gets me back on track. Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure, glad your issue is resolved. Enjoy :-)